# Erro "HTML contains invalid UTF-8 character(s)" ao usar mpdf

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Estou com um problema ao usar o mPDF. Basicamente, tenho um código que faz um `select` de uma tabela e depois apresenta os valores numa página PDF.

O problema é que se algum valor da tabela tiver um acento(exemplo: "Olá") aparece o erro:

> "HTML contains invalid UTF-8 character(s)"

Se eu retirar o acento, o valor é apresentado corretamente. Existe alguma maneira de manter os acentos?

Aqui está o meu código se alguém quiser dar uma olhada:

```
<?php

ob_start();  

?>

<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<?php       

mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("db1") or die(mysql_error());

$count=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teste_2");
$count_fin=mysql_num_rows($count);
$x=1;

while($x<=$count_fin){
    //$id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT questao from db1.teste_2 where id_quest=$x");
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $Array[$x]=$info['questao'];
    }

    echo $Array[$x];  
    echo '<hr>';     
    echo'<br>';     
    $x = $x + 1;    
}

$html='<php echo $count_fin;?>'; //setcookie ("Nome_ques", "", time() - 3600); ?>
    </body>

    </html>
    <?php

$HTMLoutput= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

//
include("mpdf/MPDF57/mpdf.php");  
$mpdf=new mPDF();  
$mpdf->WriteHTML($HTMLoutput);  
$mpdf->Output();   

?>
```

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Já encontrei a solução. Bastava adicionar $mpdf->charset_in='windows-1252';

Comment: Coloca a tua solução com uma resposta dando conta que o MPDF carece a indicação do _charset_ de forma a correctamente trabalhar os valores. Depois marca a tua resposta como aceite para fechar este tópico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já encontrei a solução. Bastava adicionar `$mpdf->charset_in='windows-1252'`.

Exemplo:

```
include("mpdf/MPDF57/mpdf.php");  
$mpdf=new mPDF();  
$mpdf->WriteHTML($HTMLoutput);  
$mpdf->Output();   
$mpdf->charset_in='windows-1252';
```

Answer (score 2):

Tive o mesmo problema  que consegui resolver somente assim:

```
$html = utf8_encode($html1);
```

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28736069

No meu caso o pdf está formatado com utf8

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-R');
```

Ao longo do pdf existem acentos e caracteres especiais que nao geram erro, porem quando user a funcao strftime para formatar data por extenso é que ocorreu o erro quando o dia de semana é terça-feira.

Usei a solução somente nessa função da seguinte maneira:

```
utf8_encode((strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y', strtotime($data))))
```

Answer (score -1):

Para que não haja quebra nas charset e não precise ficar mudando cada caracteres especial pois a solução acima traz outro trasmonto o de poder acontecer os erros em outro caracteres que não vem da tabela

Por exemplo, basta colocar:

```
utf8_encode($tabela['title'];)
```